# Where to load javascript for dialog boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a form which I want to open in a jQuery dialog.  The form has a lot of javascript in it, and may be opened multiple times without navigating away from the underlying page.

Where should I load the javascript for this form?  Should I load it once when the underlying document loads?  Or should I load it each time the dialog is opened?  How do I decide?